# How to convert NSString to Int so I can add in swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I have a value which seems to be an `Int` but when I do `type(of: value)` it returns `Optional<Any>` and after trying many things I figure that data type `NSString`.

```
let sum = data[0]["total1"] + data[0]["total2"]
```

I have two values like that and I want to add them but it does not let me do it with saying

> binary operator + cannot be applied to two "Any" operands

or

> Value of type "Any" has no member 'intValue'

How do I convert this `Any` to `Int` so I can add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the underlying objects are `NSString`, you can also do:

```
if let num1 = (data[0]["total1"] as? NSString)?.intValue,
   let num2 = (data[0]["total2"] as? NSString)?.intValue {
    let sum = num1 + num2
}
```

As @rmaddy pointed out in the comments, if a value is not an integer (such as `"hello"`), it will convert to `0`.  Depending on your knowledge of the data your app is receiving and what you want to happen in this case, that result may or may not be appropriate.

`.intValue` is more forgiving of the string data format compared to `Int(str)`.  Leading and trailing spaces are ignored and a floating point value such as `13.1` will be converted to an integer.  Again, it depends on what you want to happen in your app.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that if the strings are not numbers, you get 0. That may or may not be appropriate depending on the needs of the app.

Comment: @rmaddy, good point.  On the other hand, it is more forgiving of leading and trailing spaces and will at least convert `"13.1"` to `13`.

Comment: be aware that this would crash if data.isEmpty. same issue present in rmaddy post

Answer (score 6):

Use optional binding to ensure the values are non-nil strings and that they can be converted to `Int`.

```
if let str1 = data[0]["total1"] as? String, let str2 = data[0]["total2"] as? String {
    if let int1 = Int(str1), let int2 = Int(str2) {
        let sum = int1 + int2
    } else {
        // One or more of the two strings doesn't represent an integer
    }
} else {
    // One or more of the two values is nil or not a String
}
```

Comment: You can get by with a single `if let` here if you don't care about distinguishing between missing keys and values that aren't convertible to `Int`.

Comment: @BallpointBen Just because you can doesn't mean you should. :) I like to keep it readable and debuggable. With one long `if` you don't know which failed.

Comment: I would just change `[0]` to  `if let str1 = data.first?["total1"] as? String, let str2 = data.first?["total2"] as? String {` s it doesn't crash when `data.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
extension String {
    var asInt: Int? {
        return Int(self)
    }
    var isInt: Bool {
        return Int(self) != nil
    }
}

call it as follows (assuming a property called result):

        let stringOne = "14"
        let stringTwo = "12"
        if  stringOne.isInt && stringTwo.isInt {
            self.result = stringOne.asInt + stringTwo.asInt
        }
```

Comment: Meh, seems to be more work to check if `isInt` and then calling `asInt` instead of just wrapping the `Int` constructor in an `if let` or `guard let`.  Don't fight optionals!

Comment: I hear you. It's not so much fighting them, as easing into them. Some people need repeated exposure to optionals before they fully understand them.

Comment: @JAL, you contradict yourself -- I think you meant "Don't fight optionals?"

Comment: This code is very inefficient. You end up parsing each string into an `Int` twice. And this answer doesn't address the source of strings and making sure that are not nil.

Comment: I agree the code is inefficient, but feel it's worth it if the OP understands the code better. "How do I convert this "Any" to Int so I can add them" is answered properly. I just saw your answer and have upvoted it.